Volume enclosed by $\rho=\cos\phi$, $\rho=1-\cos\phi$
Problem :
Let $E$ an area which is enclosed by two surface $\rho=\cos\phi$, $\rho=1-\cos\phi$ $\left(0\leq \phi\leq \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$.
Evaluate
$$\iiint_E dV$$

I know that this problem is actually same as evaluate $\text{Vol}(E)$.
But there is a problem : if $\phi = \frac{\pi}{3}$, two surfaces are actually equal.
So, I don't know how to set a integral bound in spherical coordinates.
I think I should set bound of $\rho$ as :
$$\min({\cos\phi, 1-\cos\phi})\leq \rho \leq\max({\cos\phi, 1-\cos\phi})$$
But I still have a problem : how should I set a integral bound of $\theta$?
Thanks for help.

Notice that the first surface is a sphere of radius $\dfrac12$, hence with volume $\dfrac\pi6$:
$$\rho=\cos\phi \implies \rho^2=\rho\cos\phi \implies x^2+y^2+\left(z-\frac12\right)^2 = \frac14$$
The volume of $E$ can then be obtained by subtracting the volume enclosed by this sphere, but not by $\rho=1-\cos\phi$, from the sphere's known volume.
$$\iiint_E dV = \frac\pi6 - \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\tfrac\pi3 \int_{1-\cos\phi}^{\cos\phi} \rho^2 \sin\phi \, d\rho \, d\phi \, d\theta$$
The limits on the integral w.r.t. $\theta$ follow from the fact that both given equations are independent of $\theta$.
